# Compare numbers in form: 12,3K , 1,84M in python

Tags: python, numbers, compare

In need to compare numbers which look like: 12,3K , 1,84M, etc
eg:

```
a = 12,3K 
b = 1,84M
if b > a :
    print b
```

Comment: should a and b be strings?

Comment: Do you mean by ``k`` ``*1000`` and with ``M`` ``*1000000``? And use ``.`` instead of ``,`` while defining numbers. So ``a=12.3 * 1000`` instead of ``12,3K``?

Comment: Write a function that takes a string like "12.3K" and converts it to the number 12300. The function would look at the last character of the string and convert it to 1000 for K, 1000000 for M, etc. It might also have to swap commas for periods if the numbers are already in that format.

Comment: @MSeifert: The use of `.` or `,` depends on locality.

Comment: Not in python there ``a = 12,3`` is translated as ``a = tuple(12, 3)``

Comment: @Michalis T. Please alter your example code. You should have a and be representing strings and therefore it should be something like `a,b="12,3K", "1,84M"`.

Comment: @NisseEngström - But I think the OP wants to evaluate from user input so I misunderstood the question. Then you are right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use replace for it:

```
a = ("12,3K", "1,84M")
numbers = {"K": 1000, "M": 1000000}

result = []

for value in a:
    if value:
        i = value[-1]
        value = float(value[:-1].replace(',', '.')) * numbers[i]
        result.append(int(value))

print max(result)
```

You can add more numbers to dictionary and you will get more results.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend a function to convert `a` and `b` into the corresponding number like so (also I'd make `a` and `b` strings:

```
def convert(num):
    return num.replace(',','').replace('K','000').replace('M','000000')

a = '12,3K'
b = '1,84M'
if convert(b) > convert(a) :
    print b
```

Comment: I appreciate your trying for help , actually i get a list from web scraping in form: ['12.3K' , '234' , '1.84M' , '23'] and i want to compare this with another list in the same form

Answer (score 0):

If your values are strings, then the `re` module would make it easy to replace commas with `''` and K or M with 3 or 6 zeroes. Then wrap in `int()` and compare. Where / how are you getting the values you're comparing?

Comment: basicly i get them from a web scraping, like : ['12.3K' , '123' , '1.34M' , '34']

Comment: and i want to compare them with another list in form: ['10.9K' , '123' , '2.67M' , '34']